# Create plotly chart in R to toggle between count and percentage

Tags: r, plotly, ggplotly

The general idea is to create a plotly chart that can toggled between showing a count and a percentage. I am able to change which traces are shown using updatemenu, and the axis ticks can change dynamically, but when I toggle to "%" in the example below, the legend disappears.

I'm not at all a plotly pro which is why I'm using `ggplotly()` (my real example is more complex and `ggplolty()` works great!) and I'm wondering if I have to manually add a legend to % traces (3, 4) to have a legend displayed when the first traces are made invisible?

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(plotly)

df <- structure(list(outcome = c("a", "b", "a", "b", "a", "b", "a", 
"b", "a", "b"), n = c(59, 191, 28, 67, 29, 56, 33, 45, 32, 40
), pct = c(0.208480565371025, 0.674911660777385, 0.288659793814433, 
0.690721649484536, 0.337209302325581, 0.651162790697674, 0.4125, 
0.5625, 0.444444444444444, 0.555555555555556), day = c(1L, 1L, 
2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L)), class = "data.frame",
row.names = c(NA, -10L))

p <- ggplot(df, aes(day, n, color = outcome)) +
  geom_line() +
  geom_line(aes(y = pct))

ggplotly(p, dynamicTicks = TRUE) %>% 
  style(visible = FALSE, traces = 3:4) %>% 
  layout(
    updatemenus = list(
      list(
        buttons = list(
          list(args = list("visible", list(TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE)),
               label = "n"),

          list(args = list("visible", list(FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE)),
               label = "%")
          )
        )
      )
    )
```

[image]

[image]

NOTE: This is also posted on [RStudio Community](https://community.rstudio.com/t/keeping-legend-when-using-plotly-updatemenu-drop-down/63278), but has not received any answers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

@mfherman - here's what I came up with:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(plotly)
library(scales)

df <- structure(list(outcome = c("a", "b", "a", "b", "a", "b", "a", 
                                 "b", "a", "b"), n = c(59, 191, 28, 67, 29, 56, 33, 45, 32, 40
                                 ), pct = c(0.208480565371025, 0.674911660777385, 0.288659793814433, 
                                            0.690721649484536, 0.337209302325581, 0.651162790697674, 0.4125, 
                                            0.5625, 0.444444444444444, 0.555555555555556), day = c(1L, 1L, 
                                                                                                   2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L)), class = "data.frame",
                row.names = c(NA, -10L))

p <- ggplot(df, aes(day, n, color = outcome)) +
  geom_line() +
  geom_line(aes(y = pct)) + 
  theme(legend.position="bottom", legend.box = "horizontal")



chart_type <- list(
  type = "buttons",
  direction = "right",
  xanchor = 'center',
  yanchor = "top",
  x = 0.5,
  y = 1.27,
  buttons = list(
    list(
      label = "nvals",
      method = "update",
      args = list( list("visible", list(TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE)), 
                   list( yaxis = list( range = c(0,200) ,
                                       ticksuffix = "") )
                  )),
    list(
        label = "%vals",
        method = "update",
        args = list( list("visible", list(FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE)), 
                     list( yaxis = list( range = c(0,100) ,
                                         ticksuffix = "%") )
        ))
  ))

# https://plotly.com/r/custom-buttons/#relayout-button



p2 <- ggplotly(p, dynamicTicks = TRUE, width = 640, height = 420) %>% 
  style(visible = FALSE, traces = 3:4) %>% 
  layout(
      legend = list(orientation = "h",y = 0.8, x = 0.8),
      updatemenus = list( chart_type )
)


for (i in 1:ncol(df)){
  p2$x$data[[i]]$showlegend <- TRUE
}
p2
```

Important part is at the bottom -> looks like the `p2$x$data[[i]]$showlegend` values are being set to false on the second chart by default. Might be worth opening as an issue on the github project for this to be added as an option on the layout list. Looks like they have a `hide_legend` option only right now... weird.

https://github.com/ropensci/plotly/issues

Kudos to this issue for helping me figure this out:

https://github.com/ropensci/plotly/issues/842

[image]
[image]

EDIT: added % yaxis as requested in comment

Comment: This is it, thanks! A tangential question is how to get the y axis label to change to % format when the drop down is selected. It looks like you can specify a layout change in a button, but I haven't yet been able to get it to change both the layout and style in one button.

Comment: Added the % yaxis for you and cleaned up the button list methods for you. Learned quite a bit about plotly doing this exercise.